# Pluggable Annotations Java 6 new feature

Tags: java, annotations

Annotations have been introduced from Java 5.0 (**JSR-175**).Java 6 has introduced a new JSR called **JSR-269**, which is the **Pluggable Annotation Processing API**.

I am trying to learn about Pluggable Annotation but unable to get it properly,so asking in SO.

1. What Pluggable Annotation is actually ?
2. How it is different from **Annotations** and what are the **extra features Pluggable Annotation (JSR-269) provides over Annotations (JSR-175)**
3. I am looking for a way to take **advantages of Pluggable Annotation**, how can I achieve that? (practical scenario).

Comment: Sorry, but what prior research did you do at all? Googling for JSR-269 gives me a whole set of links very much look like they answer most if not all of your questions?! And I guess it took me only a fraction of the time that you invested to write up this question ...

Answer (score 2):

It's not the annotations that are "pluggable", but rather the entire processing API. Nothing changed about annotations; just the way they are processed. If you read the [JSR-269 outline](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=269), it makes this clear: "this JSR will define APIs to allow annotation processors to be created using a standard pluggable API."